# How to multiple tabs align vertically using ext js5

Tags: asp.net, extjs5

I created tabs horizontally, like this:

```
tab1 tab2 tab3 tab4
```

But here I want tabs vertically like this:

```
tab1  
tab2  
tab3  
tab4
```

I am using this code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    renderTo: document.body,

    items: [
        {

        title: 'Stock Information' },
        { title: 'Score Analysis'},
        {title:'SeverityAnalysis'},
        {title:'Historical Analysis'
    }]

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the config options:

```
tabPosition: 'left',
tabRotation: 0,
titleRotation: 0,
```

The whole code would then be:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        renderTo: document.body,
        tabPosition: 'left',
        tabRotation: 0,
        titleRotation: 0,

        items: [{
            title: 'Stock Information'
        }, {
            title: 'Score Analysis'
        }, {
            title: 'SeverityAnalysis'
        }, {
            title: 'Historical Analysis'
        }]

    });
```

See example [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/kr8)